# Jboss Eap 7.3 deployment error: Unable to access binding information for class

Tags: jboss, jibx

Getting the following error while starting the server after Jboss upgrade from 4.2 to 7.3. There are no changes made to the code.

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Unable to access binding information for class com.test.model.entity.Entity
Make sure classes generated by the binding compiler are available at runtime

jibx version used is 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest JiBX version 1.4.2.